# Why my player can't play video when XML store 2 data in Adobe Air AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air

I'm making an android app using Adobe AIR AS3. My program works fine and the video can play when I have only 1 data on XML. But when I have 2 or more data, I can't play the video, even when the image loaded just fine. Is there anything that I missed on my program? Here is the entire my AS3 script and my xml data.

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.media.Video;
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.net.NetConnection;
import flash.net.NetStream;
import flash.events.NetStatusEvent;
import flash.events.AsyncErrorEvent;
import flash.ui.Mouse;
import flash.media.SoundTransform;
import flash.geom.Rectangle;

stage.scaleMode=StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
stage.align=StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;
stage.displayState=StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN;
FilterShortcuts.init();

stop();

var mainBtn:MovieClip = btnMain;
var helpBtn:MovieClip = btnHelp;
var exitBtn:MovieClip = btnExit;    
var mainPage:MovieClip = mcMainMenu;
    var logoIcon:MovieClip = mcIcon;    
var contentPage:MovieClip = mcContent;
    var videoBox:MovieClip = mcContent.mcVideoArea;
    var playBtn:MovieClip = mcContent.btnPlay;
    var pauseBtn:MovieClip = mcContent.btnPause;
    var timelineSlider:MovieClip = mcContent.mcTimelineSlider;
    var timelineBuffer:MovieClip = mcContent.mcTimelineSlider.mcTimelineBuffer;
    var timelineProgress:MovieClip = mcContent.mcTimelineSlider.mcTimelineProgress;
    var timelineBtn:MovieClip = mcContent.mcTimelineSlider.btnTimeline;
var volumeSlider:MovieClip = mcContent.mcVolumeSlider;
    var volumeBtn:MovieClip = mcContent.mcVolumeSlider.btnVolume;
    var volumeActive:MovieClip = mcContent.mcVolumeSlider.mcVolumeActive;   
var helpPage:MovieClip = mcHelpPage;
var backBtn:MovieClip = mcHelpPage.btnCancel;   
var exitPage:MovieClip = mcExitPage;
var yesBtn:MovieClip = mcExitPage.btnYes;
var noBtn:MovieClip = mcExitPage.btnNo; 
mainPage.visible=true;
logoIcon.visible=true;
contentPage.visible=false;
mainBtn.visible=false;
helpPage.visible=false;
exitPage.visible=false;
var currentVideo:String;
var videoWidth:Number=1280;
var videoHeight:Number=720;
var duration:Number;
var video:Video=new Video(videoWidth, videoHeight);
video.x=-640;
video.y=-360;
videoBox.addChild(video);
var nc:NetConnection=new NetConnection();
nc.connect(null);
var ns:NetStream=new NetStream(nc);
video.attachNetStream(ns);
var newMeta:Object=new Object();
newMeta.onMetaData=onMetaData;
ns.client=newMeta;
ns.bufferTime=5;
var videoSound=SoundTransform;
var volumeBounds:Rectangle;
videoSound=new SoundTransform();
videoSound.volume=.5;
ns.soundTransform=videoSound;
var videoInterval=setInterval(videoStatus, 100);
var amountLoaded:Number;
var scrubInterval;
var mcContainer:MovieClip;
var xmlPath:String="list.xml";
var xml:XML;
var loader=new URLLoader();
var currentThumb:Number=0;
var i:Number=0;
var videoThumbLoader:Loader;
var videoItemName:String;
var columns:Number=6;
var xCount:Number;
var yCount:Number;

mainBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, gotoMain);
helpBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, gotoHelp);
exitBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, gotoExit);   
backBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, goBack);
yesBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, exitApp);
noBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, goBack);
ns.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, myStatusHandler);
playBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,playBtnClick);
pauseBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,pauseBtnClick);
volumeBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN,volumeScrubberDown);
timelineBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, videoScrubberDown);
loader.load(new URLRequest(xmlPath));
loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,xmlLoaded);

function gotoMain(e:MouseEvent):void{
mainPage.visible=true;
    logoIcon.visible=true;  
contentPage.visible=false;
    mainBtn.visible=false;
flash.media.SoundMixer.stopAll();
}
function gotoHelp(e:MouseEvent):void{
helpPage.visible=true;
ns.pause();
}
function goBack(e:MouseEvent):void{
helpPage.visible=false;
exitPage.visible=false;
ns.resume();
}
function gotoExit(e:MouseEvent):void{
helpPage.visible=false;
exitPage.visible=true;
ns.pause();
}
function exitApp(e:MouseEvent):void{
NativeApplication.nativeApplication.exit();
}

function myStatusHandler(e:NetStatusEvent):void{
//trace(e.info.code);
switch(e.info.code){
    case "NetStream.Buffer.Full":
        ns.bufferTime=10;
    break;
    case "NetStream.Buffer.Empty":
        ns.bufferTime=10;
    break;
    case "NetStream.Play.Start":
        ns.bufferTime=10;
    break;
    case "NetStream.Seek.Notify":
        ns.bufferTime=10;
    break;
    case "NetStream.Seek.InvalidTime":
        ns.bufferTime=10;
    break;
    case "NetStream.Play.Stop":
        ns.pause();
        ns.seek(1);
    break;
}
}
function onMetaData(newMeta:Object):void{
//trace("Metadata:duration="+newMeta.duration+" width="+newMeta.width+" height="+newMeta.height+" framerate"+newMeta.framerate);
duration=newMeta.duration;
}

function playBtnClick(e:MouseEvent):void{
ns.resume();
}
function pauseBtnClick(e:MouseEvent):void{
ns.pause();
}

function volumeScrubberDown(e:MouseEvent):void{
volumeBounds=new Rectangle(0,0,169,0);
volumeBtn.startDrag(false,volumeBounds);
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP,volumeBtnUp);
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE,volumeBtnMove);
}
function volumeBtnUp(e:MouseEvent):void{
volumeBtn.stopDrag();
stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, volumeBtnUp);
stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, volumeBtnMove);
}
function volumeBtnMove(e:MouseEvent):void{
volumeActive.width=volumeBtn.x;
videoSound.volume=(volumeBtn.x)/50;
ns.soundTransform=videoSound;
}

function videoStatus():void{
amountLoaded=ns.bytesLoaded/ns.bytesTotal;
timelineBuffer.width=amountLoaded*900;
timelineBtn.x=ns.time/duration*900;
timelineProgress.width=timelineBtn.x;
}
function videoScrubberDown(e:MouseEvent):void{
var bounds:Rectangle=new Rectangle(0,0,900,0);
clearInterval(videoInterval);
scrubInterval=setInterval(scrubTimeline,10);
timelineBtn.startDrag(false,bounds);
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP,stopScrubbingVideo);
}
function scrubTimeline():void{
ns.seek(Math.floor((timelineBtn.x/900)*duration));
}
function stopScrubbingVideo(e:MouseEvent):void{
stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP,stopScrubbingVideo);
clearInterval(scrubInterval);
videoInterval=setInterval(videoStatus,100);
timelineBtn.stopDrag();
}

function xmlLoaded(e:Event):void{
if((e.target as URLLoader)!=null){
    xml = new XML(loader.data);
    loader.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, xmlLoaded);
    makeVideoThumb();
    //trace(xml);
}
}
function makeVideoThumb():void{
xCount=0;
yCount=0;
mcContainer=new MovieClip();
mcContainer.x=-600; //set the container x position
mcContainer.y=-255; //set the container y position
mainPage.addChild(mcContainer);
if(i>0){
    i=0;
}
for each(var videoNode:XML in xml.content){
    var videoItem:mc_thumbContainer=new mc_thumbContainer();
        videoItem.txtVideoTitle.text=videoNode.@title;
        videoItem.txtVideoCountry.text=videoNode.@country;
        videoItem.x=(videoItem.width+30)*xCount;
        videoItem.y=(videoItem.height+30)*yCount;
        videoItem.name=""+i;
        videoItem.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, videoItemClick);
    var videoThumbURL=videoNode.@cover;
        videoThumbLoader=new Loader();          
        videoThumbLoader.load(new URLRequest(videoThumbURL));
        videoThumbLoader.x=6;
        videoThumbLoader.y=5;
        videoItem.addChild(videoThumbLoader);
    videoThumbLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, videoThumbLoaded);
    mcContainer.addChild(videoItem);
    i++;
    if(xCount+1<columns){
        xCount++;
    }else{
        xCount=0;
        yCount++;
    }
}
}
function videoThumbLoaded(e:Event):void{
videoThumbLoader.contentLoaderInfo.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, videoThumbLoaded);   
}
function videoItemClick(e:MouseEvent):void{
videoItemName=e.target.name;
currentVideo=xml.content.@video;
mainPage.visible=false;
    logoIcon.visible=false;
contentPage.visible=true;
    mainBtn.visible=true;
video.width=videoWidth;
video.height=videoHeight;
ns.play(currentVideo);
}
```

And here is the xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<list>
  <content id="1" title="story" country="England" cover="http://localhost:280/list//content/cover/6a778-cover-72.jpg" video="http://localhost:280/list//content/video/e27f9-video.mp4"/>
  <content id="2" title="story-2" country="England" cover="http://localhost:280/list//content/cover/2e383-cover-72.jpg" video="http://localhost:280/list//content/video/cce76-video.mp4"/>      
</list>
```

Comment: I don't know if this code is yours or not, but you can create a playlist of your multiple videos and everytime play the selected video by the user ... And for the XML, you should use the same attribute name for all your XML lines ( cover != sampul) ...

Comment: @akmozo thanks for your response. But I don't understand with your suggestion to create a playlist. Could you explain more, please? And for the XML, it's my bad. I changed the attribute before asked the question and I missed that one.

Comment: By a playlist, I meant after loading your XML data, you can create a list of all your videos (with all their parameters) and then just play the selected video using, for example, a `play_video(index_of_the_video)` function, so the number of videos doesn't matter in that case because that function will just play a video whatever the number of videos is ...